# Create a zip folder using vbscript and wmi without using CopyHere

Tags: vbscript, zip, compression, wmi

I am trying to write a function in VBScript that creates a zipped folder from another regular folder. The problem is that **my lecturer said I can't use `.CopyHere` method** like in this code:

```
Sub ArchiveFolder (zipFile, sFolder)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
        sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

        With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
            .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items

        Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count
            WScript.Sleep 1000 
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

I can create the zip file but I can't copy my files inside it (`.MoveHere` is also deprecated **by my lecturer**). Is there any way to copy the files using WMI or some other Windows component?

Comment: **No** to your question. `MoveHere` is not depreciated either. If you want to state things not true you need to prove it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder-movehere and the words *May not be supported in a future version* are not on the page AT ALL. So don't spread untruths.

Comment: That's why I said you have to use a .NET language. The fraud was editing his question then pretending he hadn't. Notice ***by my lecturer*** was added 25 mins after I said it wasn't depreciated (a statement of fact). And after doing that he posted a comment *Read the question again, i didn't said that it's deprecated by microsoft, it's depricated by my lecturer*.

Comment: @CatCat That's still nowhere near fraud. It's probably just poor choice of words of a non-native speaker. Don't blow things out of proportion.

Comment: My answer was **NO**. You cannot do this in vbscript using windows published COM API calls. You can make `.cab` files though by shelling to `makecab`. Or even IExpress can make cab files.

Comment: Perhaps your lecturer is thinking about the `compress` method of `CIM_DataFile` object. This does NTFS compression. The WMI equiv of your code is not implemented by Windows `Invoke Takes a particular action. This method is not implemented by WMI. `